# Audio playback using Gstreamer on OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-mavericks, gstreamer

I am trying to play mp3 audio on Mac OS X Mavericks(VirtualBox) using these pipelines:

> gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/test.mp3
>
> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! 
>   audioresample ! autoaudiosink
>
> gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///path/to/test.mp3 ! 
>   audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink

But always get this output:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 
>   0:00:00.032003000  4120 0x7fe62bcd4900 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3470:void gst_base_src_start_complete(GstBaseSrc *, GstFlowReturn): pad not activated yet 
>   0:00:00.033290000  4120 0x7fe62bcd4900 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3470:void gst_base_src_start_complete(GstBaseSrc *, GstFlowReturn): pad not activated yet 
>   Pipeline is PREROLLING ... 
>   
> 0:00:00.106320000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN            osxaudiosink gstosxaudiosink.c:601:gst_osx_audio_sink_allowed_caps: unrecognized channel: -1 
>   
> 0:00:00.106584000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN            osxaudiosink gstosxaudiosink.c:601:gst_osx_audio_sink_allowed_caps: unrecognized channel: -1 
>   
> 0:00:00.128755000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN           audioresample gstaudioresample.c:1537:gboolean plugin_init(GstPlugin *): Orc disabled, can't benchmark int vs. float resampler 
>   
> 0:00:00.129217000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN         **GST_PERFORMANCE gstaudioresample.c:1540:gboolean plugin_init(GstPlugin *):** orc disabled, no benchmarking done 
>   
> 0:00:00.133383000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN               baseparse gstbaseparse.c:3264:void gst_base_parse_loop(GstPad *): error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated 
>   
> 0:00:00.133718000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:860:gboolean gst_queue_handle_sink_event(GstPad *, GstObject *, GstEvent *): error: Internal data flow error. 
>   
> ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegAudioParse:mpegaudioparse0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error. 
>   
> 0:00:00.134308000  4120 0x7fe62c032140 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:860:gboolean gst_queue_handle_sink_event(GstPad *, GstObject *, GstEvent *): error: streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4) 
>   
> Additional debug info: 
>   
> gstbaseparse.c(3264): void gst_base_parse_loop(GstPad *) (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstMpegAudioParse:mpegaudioparse0: 
>   streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated 
>   
> ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll. 
>   
> Setting pipeline to NULL ... 
>   
> Freeing pipeline ...

Identical pipeline works fine on Windows 7 with the same audio.

**How I can resolve this issue on Mac OS X Mavericks?**

Comment: what gstreamer version are you using? sounds like a bug..

Comment: @otopolsky gstreamer 1.4.5. May be it's the problem due to I use OS X on VirtualBox?

Comment: [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/no-working-native-video-sinks-on-osx-td3470581.html)  is interesting post - maybe a little bit out of date.. you could also try new stable release 1.6 there are improvements in OSX support as well.. or you may try to check other sinks like sdlvideosink or glvideosink (you have to install something and it may not work in VirtualBox..)

Comment: @otopolsky ok, thanks! I will check the post and I will try to use these sinks. But how I can update gstreamer? I installed it using homebrew.

Comment: I installed gstreamer 1.6 by compiling it (on Linux) .. also I found [this](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.6.0/) I do not know if its usable..

Answer (score 2):

A little late to respond, but though would put it in here in case anyone else has same problem.

On mac we need proper pipeline and pipeline elements such as decoder and sink.
using `autoaudiosink`, `gstreamer` will find sink automatically.
Or you can provide mac specific `osxaudiosink`.

Try

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert !
audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///path/to/test.mp3 !
audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosin
```